# SPL token metadata update

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, metadata

Our program currently has mint authority but lacks metadata authority, preventing us from updating metadata on our SPL token. Have we explored any solutions for this issue? Attempts to transfer authority and change metadata with Metaboss proved unsuccessful. Although we successfully transferred authority, the token metadata update still did not work. Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.